# Unable to create account in Sendgrid. Getting, You are not authorized to access SendGrid, please contact

Tags: drupal, twilio, drupal-7, sendgrid, drupal-modules

**I'm working with drupal 10**, i want to work with Sendgrid module

I tried to create sendgrid account.I have entered all the basic details it asked. Then I got two mails Two-Factor Authentication & also another mail like " your account and have determined that Twilio’s services cannot support your account at this time " i don't known what happened I was creating first time my account in this.

**Some Violations mail i got:-**
[[image: Some Violations mail i got]

**When i click 2Factor Authentication from other mail i got,I am redirecting to the Login Page. And when i try to log in, I'm getting this**

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry you were not able to create an account. Do you believe it was a mistake that the account was closed? If so, can you try to respond to the email you received?

Comment: @IObert it not a mistake its happening again and your support system cannot be reached without login ( the main problem is that  you guys want us to  login to say that we are not able to login , that sucks ).  I am now forced to move to a diffrent system due to this reason and now have to rewrite all my code again to mailgun or mailchimp

Comment: Same thing happend with me too. I was going to integrate twillio and sengrid with an enterprise application, so wanted an account to build a POC. Now, I need to find another alternative. Thank goodness, there are many :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created sendgrid account using another mail ( eg: abc@gmail.com ). And account got created successfully. After creating account i changed drupal site mail as well because sendgrid & drupal site mail should be same. So,
**admin> Configuration> system> Basic site settings** here i changed my mail that linked to sendgrid ( abc@gmail.com ) now it worked for me.

**Don't know why my other account got violations.
I texted twillo team but no use. So i proceeded by adding new mail in both.**